# removing elements from array which are not numbers using pure js

Tags: pure-js

I'm stuck with one task, hope you could help me

I have to return an combined array which consist only from numbers. So if the element has got except for number another character, such element should be removed.

I had few ideas. Unfortunately, none of them work properly.
providing my code

```
function combineArray(arr1, arr2) {
    let array1 = filt(arr1);
    let array2 = filt(arr2);
    let arr3 = array1.concat(array2);
    return arr3;
}
function filt(array){
  array.forEach(function(item,index) {
    if (typeof item !== 'number'){
      array.splice(index, 1);
  }
  })
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Please provide example input/output for us to test.

Comment: console.log(['item1', 2, 3, 'item4'],['1','second','3rd',4]);
the answer should be [2,3,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that uses the `filter` method on arrays and `Number.isFinite` to check if a variable is a number:

```js
function combineArray(arr1, arr2) {
    let array1 = filt(arr1);
    let array2 = filt(arr2);
    let arr3 = array1.concat(array2);
    return arr3;
}

function filt(array) {
  return array.filter(x => Number.isFinite(x));
}


console.log(combineArray(['item1', 2, 3, 'item4'],['1','second','3rd',4]));
```

This outputs: `[2, 3, 4]`

Comment: never heard before about isFinite()
thanks a lot!

Comment: If the answer helped you don't hesitate to close your question by accepting it as the answer :')